# Authenticate as a service account from Android app for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth-java-client

I have an Android app that will be eventually storing user-generated content in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. But I am unable to do so from my app code. The code looks like this:

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
KeyStore keystore = SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore();
keystore.load(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.secret), "***password***".toCharArray()); 
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("privatekey", "***password***".toCharArray());
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(httpTransport)
.setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
.setServiceAccountPrivateKey(key)
.setServiceAccountId("**************@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
.setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_WRITE))
.build();
credential.refreshToken();
String URI = "https://storage.googleapis.com/"+BUCKET_NAME;
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI);
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
HttpResponse response = request.execute();
String content = response.parseAsString();
Log.d("testing", "response content is: " + content);
new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Doubts").build();
```

I am getting various errors. One of them is:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

The official documentation simply ignores the use case from an Android app.

Comment: binaryking> Even if this worked - would you embed private key / password inside your android app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to take the responsibility of authorizing the request away from your Android client, as it is not considered a "trustable" client.

A good practice to follow would be to generate a signed URL server side and send that to the client so that the latter can use it to upload files to your buckets in a secure and opaque manner. This way you'll also remove the complexity and exposure to naturally private credentials from your clients.

You can find more about signed URLs in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs)